# Painting on CDC with 32bpp bitmap and alpha blending

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm facing problem in alpha blending 32bpp bitmap into memory DC. Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Create `CMemDC` based on `CPaintDC`
- Create compatible `CDC` and 32bpp bitmap
- Draw on compatible dc
- `AlphaBlend` compatible dc into `CMemDC`

And as a result I can't see anything that was drawn on compatible dc. Seems that after painting all pixels of compatible dc got alpha value = 0.

Here's a small oversimplified example that reproduces the issue:

```cpp
void CTestDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC paintDC(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    // Create memory DC
    CMemDC memDC(paintDC, rect);
    CDC* pMemDC = &memDC.GetDC();
    pMemDC->FillSolidRect(rect, RGB(128, 128, 128)); // Fill with a gray background

    // Create yet another memory dc and 10x10 bitmap
    CRect bmpRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    CDC bmpDC;
    bmpDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pMemDC);
    CBitmap bmp;    
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pMemDC, bmpRect.Width(), bmpRect.Height());
    CBitmap* pOldBmp = (CBitmap*)bmpDC.SelectObject(&bmp);

    // At this poing all bitmap pixels have alpha = 255
    bmpDC.FillSolidRect(&bmpRect, RGB(255, 0, 0)); // Draw red rectangle
    // ISSUE: But here alpha = 0

    //AlphaBlend into memory DC
    BLENDFUNCTION bf = { AC_SRC_OVER , 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA };
    pMemDC->AlphaBlend(100, 100, bmpRect.Width(), bmpRect.Height(),
        &bmpDC, 0, 0, bmpRect.Width(), bmpRect.Height(), bf);

    // Neither memDC nor paintDC have red rectangle drawn at [100;100]

    bmpDC.SelectObject(pOldBmp);
}
```

Note: I can't draw only on one DC. The original code base is much bigger and I need to stick with such approach (`CPaintDC`->`CMemDC`->compatible `CDC` and `AlphBlend`).

My questions are: Why it happens? Why I can't see the painting result and what is the way to fix it? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `AC_SRC_ALPHA` to `0`, because the source bitmap is 24-bit without alpha channel ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_blendfunction) is a bit vague on that!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks! Such solution works for the case that I described but it makes all pixels non-transparent. If you try instead of `bmpDC.FillSolidRect(&bmpRect, RGB(255, 0, 0));` to fill only a part of that rectangle, like `bmpDC.FillSolidRect(0, 0, 5, 5, RGB(255, 0, 0));` - you'll see what I mean. How can I make the part that wasn't painted transparent? And can I?

Comment: `{AC_SRC_OVER , 0, 255, 0}` paints non-transparent. While `{AC_SRC_OVER , 0, 128, 0}` will be 50% transparent. You should explain what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you are looking for `TransparentBlt` which paints everything except the transparency color.

Comment: Most GDI drawing functions ignore alpha channel. Use a library that doesn't, like GDI+ or create a 32-bpp DIB section bitmap that allows you to manipulate pixel buffer, including alpha channel, directly through a pointer.

Comment: @zett42 Yeah, thanks. I'll go for using gdi+ I think.